# C#: Image resize and crop at the same time

Tags: c#, image, performance, resize, crop

I'm trying to write a very fast method for creating thumbnails. It will crop and resize an image at the same time. The result image will always be square-like. So having that in mind we can now look at my code :) It is working (as far as I can see):

```
    public static void CreateAndSaveThumbnail(string path, string output, int desiredSize)
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(path)))
        using (Bitmap src = new Bitmap(ms))
        {
            Rectangle crop = src.Width > src.Height ?
                new Rectangle((src.Width - src.Height) / 2, 0, src.Height, src.Height) :
                new Rectangle(0, 0, src.Width, src.Width);

            int size = Math.Min(desiredSize, crop.Width);

            using (Bitmap cropped = src.Clone(crop, src.PixelFormat))
            using (Bitmap resized = new Bitmap(size, size))
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(resized))
            {
                g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                g.DrawImage(cropped, 0, 0, size, size);
                resized.Save(output, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            }
        }
    }
```

So how the code above works? It crops the middle part for landscape images and top part for portrait images. So this is a standard behavior. Then it resizes the cropped image (it is already a square).

Is this code OK? Could it be faster? How? Any optimizations possible?

Comment: Why do you need to create a Clone Bitmap. Using the DrawImage overload with two Rectangles should do without creating the extra Bitmap, imo

Comment: I agree that you don't need the intermediate cloned bitmap. Also, it's not clear why you read the file data into memory rather than just using `Image.FromFile()` to create the original `Bitmap` object. Beyond that, your question isn't really suitable for SO, as you have code that works and thus have no specific questions about how to fix it. It really belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

Your routine works great but for one slight problem, at least in my desired application. I wanted the routine to crop portrait bitmaps the same as you do for landscape bitmaps; by cropping off half of the excess from the top and half of excess from the bitmap. So I simply duplicated the landscape crop code to the portrait crop code and adjusted as necessary resulting in this:

```
Rectangle crop = src.Width > src.Height ?
new Rectangle((src.Width - src.Height) / 2, 0, src.Height, src.Height) :
new Rectangle(0, (src.Height - src.Width) / 2, src.Width, src.Width);
```